# C# SAPI in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, sapi

```
var speechEngine = new SpVoiceClass();
SetVoice(speechEngine, job.Voice);

var fileMode = SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite;
var fileStream = new SpFileStream();
try
{
    fileStream.Open(filePath, fileMode, false);
    speechEngine.AudioOutputStream = fileStream;
    speechEngine.Speak(job.Script, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFPurgeBeforeSpeak | SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault); //TODO: Change to XML
    //Wait for 15 minutes only
    speechEngine.WaitUntilDone((uint)new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0).TotalMilliseconds);
}
finally
{
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

This exact code works in a WinForm app, but when I run it inside a webservice I get the following

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  Message="Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045003"
  Source="Interop.SpeechLib"
  ErrorCode=-2147201021
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this error?  The error code means

```
SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT
```

For completeness here is the SetVoice method

```
void SetVoice(SpVoiceClass speechEngine, string voiceName)
{
    var voices = speechEngine.GetVoices(null, null);
    for (int index = 0; index < voices.Count; index++)
    {
        var currentToken = (SpObjectToken)voices.Item(index);
        if (currentToken.GetDescription(0) == voiceName)
        {
            speechEngine.SetVoice((ISpObjectToken)currentToken);
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Voice not found: " + voiceName);
}
```

I have given full access to USERS on the folder C:\Temp where the file is to be written.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: SpeechEngine.Speak causes the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the System.Speech works in windows service. It looks like [there is a dependency to Shell](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8c408f28-0038-4478-8325-82b088602680), which isn't available to services. Try interop with SAPI's C++ interfaces. Some class in System.Runtime.InteropServices may help on that.

Answer (score 1):

Our naming convention requires us to use a non-standard file extension. This works fine in a Winforms app, but failed on our web server. Changing the file extension back to .wav solved this error for us.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you explicitly set the format on the SPFileStream object.  [ISpAudio::SetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717816(VS.85).aspx) (which gets called in a lower layer from speechEngine.Speak) will return `SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT` if the format isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the webservice to spawn a console app to do the processing.  PITA :-)